# Django, multiple DB hits when repeating one related query

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

This is the model:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Now, I want to get posts of a category:

```py
category = Category.objects.get(id=1)

posts = category.post_set.all()
# this line hit the DB

posts = category.post_set.all()
# and this line hit the DB again!
```

How to use the cached result in these relations. I use Django rest-framework and it makes DB hit multiple times for each instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
category = Category.objects.prefetch_related('posts').get(id=1)
```

This will load the related objects, and will do the JOINing at the Django/Python layer. This thus means that the `.all()` calls will use the prefetched objects.

Comment: I using `category = Category.objects.prefetch_related("post_set")` in drf view `get_queryset` function and its worked!